# Setting a cell value based on UI Alert response

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am creating a UI alert everytime someone types delivered. I tried the code blow so if they say no on the pop-up, the status reverts back to requested? Am I doing something wrong?

```js
  if (e.value == "Delivered") {
  var1 = Browser.msgBox('Has bulk been delivered?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
  var button = userChoice.getSelectedButton();
  if (var1 == ui.button.NO) {
    e.setValue('Requested');
  } else {
    ui.alert('Complete');
  }
}
```

Comment: never mind I have solved it. if (e.value == "Delivered") {
     var response = Browser.msgBox('Has bulk been delivered?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);   
    
    if (response == "no") {
            e.range.setValue('Requested');
               } else {
                 return;
}